# Difference between SQL Query and SqlClient operation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlclient

I'm attempting to query data from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a stored procedure. The code executes without error but no results are returned from the query. When this same stored procedure is invoked via SQL Server Management Studio with the exact same parameters, the data is correctly returned. I have no idea what could cause this, possibly something specific with SqlClient implementation? The query returns all data between two `DateTime2` values; if I make those `DateTime2` values far enough apart the data is returned. Obviously this isn't the desired behavior.

C# Code (`startTime.HasValue` and `endTime.HasValue` are true in this case):

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    conn.Open();
}

SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.CommandText = "GetAllPropertyValues";

comm.Parameters.Add("@dataTypeName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataTypeName;
comm.Parameters.Add("@propertyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = propertyName;

if (startTime.HasValue)
{
    var startString = startTime.Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O");

    if (endTime.HasValue)
    {
        var endString = endTime.Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O");

        comm.CommandText += "Between";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@startTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = startString;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@endTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = endString;
    }
    else
    {
        comm.CommandText += "After";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@dateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = startString;
    }
}

SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    // ...
}
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'select * from [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] where StartTime BETWEEN ''' +
                                    CAST(@startTime as nvarchar(max)) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@endTime as nvarchar(max)) + ''' order by StartTime asc'
exec(@str)
```

Executed example query:

```
USE [Construct3]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetAllPropertyValuesBetween]
        @datatypeName = N'HeadPose',
        @propertyName = N'HeadRotationRadiansZ',
        @startTime = '2014-12-31T19:00:00.0000000Z',
        @endTime = '2014-12-31T20:00:00.0000000Z'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried reading this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314505/why-some-stored-procedures-do-not-return-data-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Have you run an SQL trace to see the actual statement that is executed against the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `@startTime` and `@endTime` parameters on the stored procedure are type `DATETIME` then you're doing a double conversion from datetime to string, first you're doing it on your c# code:

`var startString = startTime.Value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O"); //This will create the datetime as a string using .NET format`

You're passing it to the stored procedure as `DateTime2`:

`comm.Parameters.Add("@startTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = startString;`

And then you're converting it back to string format on SQL:

`CAST(@startTime as nvarchar(max))`

This could be the issue, when you do conversions from `DATETIME` to string in .NET and SQL, don't expect them to have the same results, so when you execute the stored procedure on the database you get the results, but when you call it from .NET, there are no results since the dates are wrong. What I would suggest doing is passing the value of these dates parameters as normal .NET `DateTime` value and converting it to `varchar` on the stored procedure. You can use `CONVERT` function in SQL to achieve that, have a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for more info about the `CONVERT` date formats.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like this did it! I was surprised to see that this was the issue, but I took @AgustinCoder's advice to use the tracer and found that the date inputs were actually incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `CommandText` property clears the `Parameters` collection. Set all your parameter after completing your text.

Also, what you have will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You should use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), rather than `exec()`, so that your time parameters are handled safely. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that the `@tableName` parameter is not something where the user can enter arbitrary text, but rather must choose from a server-validated list of tables.